# setuid.today date format changed after FreeBSD 10.2 update

Tags: cron, freebsd, locale

My setuid.today has a different date format than setuid.yesterday:

setuid.today (German localization?)

```
3 Dez
```

setuid.yesterday

```
Dec 3
```

I'm getting emails with the diff reports every day.
I guess one of the periodic scripts changed something during the last update.
I'm on FreeBSD 10.2

How should I proceed?

Comment: Is the date format of `ls -l setuid.today` different, or is the *contents* of the setuid.today file different? From what I can tell, FreeBSD has a cron job to generate those setuid files, so if it's the latter, I would focus on cron's locale.

Comment: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/using-localization.html for more

Comment: The date ls uses is the same (also localized)

Comment: Do you have a ~/.login_conf file, or /etc/login.conf?

Comment: I have a /etc/login.conf with the localization

Comment: Does it appear to have changed? Is there a language associated with your passwd entry?

Comment: It didn't change. There is a `:lang=de_DE.UTF-8:` in the default class.

Comment: That seems likely to me to be the culprit.

Comment: So should I then delete this and set the localization in each user's `.login_conf``? Is there no other way to set this for all users? How would I then proceed with the different setuid files?

Comment: I wasn't sure which language you preferred. I've been going from the FreeBSD link I found earlier. You'll probably have to restart cron after your change to have it pick up the new locale.

Comment: seems like I didn't do that when I first changed the locale. How should I now proceed about the "wrong" setuid.yesterday? Just delete it?

Comment: Let it get overwritten with the next setuid run

Comment: sounds reasonable. Is there a way to enforce that run?

Comment: Sure! Run it manually or change the cron tab schedule for it temporarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize what we discovered in the comments:

At some point (before the upgrade), /etc/login.conf was populated with `:lang=de_DE.UTF-8` in the default class. After updating to FreeBSD 10.2, cron was presumably restarted, and picked up the new locale. The new locale caused the date formats inside the setuid.today file to change.

[The FreeBSD 10.2 Release Notes](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/10.2R/relnotes.html) don't mention changes to /etc/login.conf (closest is the [Inconsistency between locale and rune locale states](https://www.freebsd.org/security/advisories/FreeBSD-EN-15:09.xlocale.asc) patch, but it does not appear to touch /etc/login.conf).

The solution is to change the default locale back and use ~/.login_conf overrides where a different locale is desired; then restart cron.